# Android Studio - Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, certificate

I'm getting this error

`Gradle 'project_name' project refresh failed: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

when I create a new project on Android Studio 0.8.14 Mac OSX

Build.gradle file seems to become empty

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } }
```

And I can't run the project, seems that I have to configure everything manually.

Here is the idea.log http://pastebin.com/kyhfrBp9

Comment: I would say that your build.gradle file is not so empty. This is the parent build.gradle and it doesn't define any common properties. Your module files (build.gradle) will have the individual entries for the compilation units in your project.  Can you show me the contents of build.gradle (Module: ...)

Comment: when do you get this error ? Build ? Open a project ? . Is it stopping you from continuing ? Can you send that project file

Comment: Hi I have fixed this issue make sure application level build gradle dependencies example `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`  should match with **CordovaLib Dir** build gradle dependencies `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` Also, check if `repositories {
   jcenter()
}` **To** `repositories {
  maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
}`

Comment: Reboot one time

Answer (score 101):

It happened to me, and turned out it was because of **Charles Proxy**.

> **Charles Proxy** is a HTTP debugging proxy server application

Solution (only if you have Charles Proxy installed):

1. Shut down Charles Proxy;
2. Restart Android Studio.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I would not have guessed.

Comment: How do we shutdown CharlesProxy?

Comment: @AndroGeek it's a normal proxy application, just close it would be fine.  If you don't know it, it's probably not the cause of your problem.  Or you can check if you use any other proxy which might interfere your IDE's network activity.

Comment: Would have been nice to read more about what Charles Proxy is, and what it does to cause trouble. Seems it prevents SSL communication somehow...

Comment: it is like the hundredth seventh time I fix some weird issue by closing Charles, thank you

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought I was going out of my mind, but it turns out I just forgot to quit Charles over the weekend.

Comment: Sometimes shutting it down does not help: go to Proxy > Stop SSL Proxying

Answer (score 75):

***"Unable to find valid certification path to requested target"***

If you are getting this message, you probably are behind a Proxy on your company, which probably is signing all request certificates with your company root CA certificate, this certificate is trusted only inside your company, so Android Studio cannot validate any certificate signed with your company certificate as valid, so, you need to tell Android Studio to trust your company certificate, you do that by adding your company certificate to Android Studio truststore.

*(I'm doing this on macOS, but should be similar on Linux or Windows)*

- First, you need to save your company root CA certificate as a file: you can ask this certificate to your IT department, or download it yourself, here is how. Open your browser and open this url, for example, https://jcenter.bintray.com/ or https://search.maven.org/, click on the ***lock*** icon and then click on ***Show certificate***

[image]

On the popup window, to save the root certificate as a file, make sure to select the top level of the certificates chain (the root cert) and drag the certificate image to a folder/directory on your disk drive. It should be saved as a file as, for example: *my-root-ca-cert.cer*, or *my-root-ca-cert.pem*

[image]

- Second, let's add this certificate to the accepted Server Certificates of Android Studio:

On Android Studio open `Preferences -> Tools -> Server Certificates`,
on the box `Accepted certificates` click the plus icon (`+`), search the certificate you saved previously and click `Apply` and `OK`

[image]

- Third, you need to add the certificate to the Android Studio JDK truststore (Gradle use this JDK to build the project, so it's important):

In Android Studio open `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location`

[image]

Copy the path of JDK Location, and open the Terminal, and change your directory to that path, for example, execute:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/
```

(don't forget to scape the whitespace, "\ ")

Now, to import the certificate to the truststore, execute:

```
./bin/keytool -importcert -file /path/to/your/certificate/my-root-ca-cert.cer -keystore ./jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

- Finally, restart Android Studio, or better click `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Done, you should be able to build your project now.

Comment: You saved my day !! I had only imported the certificate on my JDK HOME and not in Android Studio JRE

Comment: Thank you. This is a really concise set of steps to add the certs. It really shouldn't be needed given that Android Studio has that nice tempting "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" tickbox, but you still have to do these steps.

Comment: This should be an answer. Thanks Carlos!

Comment: @Keab42 Step 3 is necessary. Step 2 (or just checking the tick box you mentioned) is for Android Studio but not Gradle. Step 3 tackles the Gradle issue.

Comment: Today, with Android Studio Artic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 freshly installed, the /jre folder not exists in my case ;)
To import the certificate to the truststore :

./bin/keytool -importcert -file /path/to/your/certificate/my-root-ca-cert.cer -keystore lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same issue with the laptop with Zscaler installed.  Your answers help to resolve the issue.

Comment: This works with windows as well, just take care to download the top level of the certificates chain (the root cert). In chrome it can be opened via double clicking top one in `Certification Path`. Also the new path for cacerts is `<Copied path of JDK Location>/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: The command to add certificate on Windows will look like `keytool -importcert -alias my-root-ca-cert -file "<Path to saved top cert>\my-root-ca-cert.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -noprompt`. Open the command prompt with administrator permissions.

Comment: Note that restarting Android Studio or `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` is not enough. You have to resart your PC.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked well with Android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3 and Oracle JDK 11.

Answer (score 26):

For me the issue was android studio was not able to establish connection with 
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/'

Changing this to 'http' fixed the issue for me (Though this is not recommended).

In your build.gradle file, change

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
}
```

to

```
repositories {
   maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. But now I am using something like artifactory to manage my repos

Comment: Please do not turn of SSL since this is a risk. Instead, import the missing certificate, see this comment below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147334/1532478

Comment: Was using gradle v2.2.2 and android Studio 3.5.3, the above solution didn't work for me.

Comment: jcenter is no longer available over http. Only https

Answer (score 21):

If you are working in a restricted workplaces you probably will encounter this problem

A combination of a few things worked for me 
Basically change https to http

From https:

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
}
```

To :

```
repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
   }
```

---

and in `gradle-wrapper.properties` ..

From :

```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

To :

```
   distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

---

And then

```
- (optional)  File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
- Give a clean build.
```

To verify :  Check your Gradle console. It should start downloading libs from jcenter via HTTP.

Comment: its worked for me distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: Please do not turn of SSL/https, this is used for good reasons. Intall the SSL certificate as descibed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147334/1532478

Comment: @trapicki I am not sure which certificate android studio is looking for. I have tried all the certificate in the link mentioned by you. Still facing the same issue. Can you point out a single certificate it is looking for ?

Comment: I have almost imported all the Digi cert certificates but no help

Answer (score 21):

Okay, Probably I am late but I have faced this issue after upgrading to 3.0.1 from 3.0. 
And this problem because I am working in restricted network.

The solution which worked for me is as follow:

**Solution**

**Step 1: Get Certificate**

`jcenter()` equals to https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

You need import jcenter's cerficate into your java keystore.

Visit jcenter using your browser and export the certificate as .cer file. (lock icon on the left of Firefox address bar, or Chrome developer tool secuity tab. Internet Explorer and Edge do not support saving of Website certificates, though.)

**Step 2: Import Certificate**
In Android Studio, go to `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates`.

Under *Accept certificates* click on `+` . Select the exported certificate.

**Step 3: Refresh Keystore** In Android Studio, go to `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`. Select `Invalidate and Restart` from the message box that appears.

Comment: how do i download the certificate ? i visited the bintray site and then ?

Comment: Visit jcenter using your browser and export the certificate as .cer file. (lock icon on the left of Firefox address bar, or Chrome developer tool secuity tab)

Comment: no i could download it and add the .cer to the accepted certificates..but android studio is showing the same error.. !!

Comment: Ask your network guy to save your IP. To allow access to all jcenter\Google Repositort URL. Or download older version of Android studio like 3.0

Comment: Didn't work :( I even checked 'Accept non-trusted certificates automatically'

Answer (score 17):

I'm in an enterprise environment with a proxy/firewall/virus-scanner combination adding the company own SSL root certificate (self signed) to the trustpath of every SSL connection to investigate also into SSL connections. That was exactly the problem. If you are in the same situation this solution could help:

1. Open https://jcenter.bintray.com in the browser (I prefer Firefox)
2. Click on the padlock symbold to check the certificated trustpath. If the top/root certificate in the tree is a certficate signed by your company export it to your harddisk.
3. To be safe export also every certificate in between
4. Open the truststore of Android Studio in path **JDKPATH/jre/lib/security/cacerts** with the Keystore Explorer tool [Keystore Exlorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) with password "changeit"
5. Import the exported certs into the trusstore starting with the root certificate of you company and go the step 6. In the most cases this will do the trick. If not, import the other certs as well step by step.
6. Save the truststore
7. Exit Android Studio with "File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart"

Comment: Followed the steps but still getting same error of SSL. 
Could not get resource :'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom'.

Comment: If you are getting this error outside of Android Studio (e.g. with React Native CLI), then you need to forcibly restart the running Java process on the host machine (e.g. through Task Manager on Windows) to get certs to update

Comment: I'd also like to mention that in some cases Gradle/React Native/Android Studio may **all** use separate JDK/JRE keystores - you need to update the CA cert caches of all of them to get each to work

Comment: First time it was not working for me.Was facing some exceptions when saving key store.**KSE Explorer** opened as Administrator ,and successfully able save to keystore and worked fine.

Comment: JDKPATH in Step 4 would typically be $JAVA_HOME. But Android Studio uses embded JRE from "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre" unless set otherwise. I got this fixed by changing "JDK Location" to value of $JAVA_HOME under File > Project Structure > SDK Location.

Answer (score 14):

Even though this question is very old, many must be facing the same issue, so I would like to state how I fixed this.

The problem is classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'`
By above line in build.gradle you are asking it to find a particular version of gradle but this version is not there in your machine. The best it to change the above line to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

Comment: After looking through all the other answers this is the one that finally worked! Thank you

Answer (score 14):

jcenter() equals to https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

You need import jcenter's cerficate into your java keystore.

Steps:

1. Visit jcenter using your browser
   and export the certificate as .crt file. (lock icon on the left of Firefox
   address bar, or Chrome developer tool secuity tab)
2. Download
   [this](http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) tool and run it.
3. Select "Open an existing KeyStore" button
   to open JDKPATH/jre/lib/security/cacerts, the password is "changeit"
4. Use the "Import Trusted Certificate" button to import the .crt file, then save and exist

If you are behind proxy, in **gradle.properties**, besides setting

**systemProp.http.proxyHost** and **systemProp.http.proxyPort**

also set

**systemProp.https.proxyHost** and **systemProp.https.proxyPort**

By now it should be fine.

Comment: Along with the bintray cert, I also had to do this for the CA Certs internal to my company network.

Comment: can you tell the process how you exported the bintray certificate ?

Comment: @SantanuSur: see below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50603870/3412545

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer: update the keystore with the custom root cert to enable proper SSL transfer.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was my internet, I was working on restricted network

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @Ali. What If I cant switch to open. Did you got any solution..?

Comment: This was my case. i switched to mobile network

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a bug to me.
I've had the same problem and worked around it by manually starting gradlew.bat in my project directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem today after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2 Beta 2.  I had configured my JDK for OpenJDK 10.0.1, and it threw this error after upgrading.  I set the JDK back to using the enbedded JDK, and the error went away.[image]

I have no idea why it worked fine before I upgraded to Beta 2, but all is good now.  Honestly I guess there is no need for OpenJDK 10 for Android.

Answer (score 3):

Try to update your Android Studio, now is version 1.0.2

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when makeing a new Android Wear OS project, and for me the problem solved just when I switched off my company's VPN for remote work and diconnected from the company network.

Answer (score 1):

Go to The Gradle Console in bottom right and open it.Here you will be seeing some https/https calls click on the links and open them in web browser then try clean build it worked for me.

I think It is happening because studio is not able to get the response from the hit.

Comment: Correct. My issue was that I was connected to a work place VPN and it was trying to build the project and to do that it was trying to automatically download the certificate but could not connect. Once I disconnected from VPN it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

My company has us using FortiClient VPN, which caused this error to occur.

Try disconnecting from your VPN if applicable, and try again.

Comment: The VPN is needed so this doesnt help much

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the problem, try deleting the directory named '**.AndroidStudio1.2**' under '**C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio1.2**'

Of course the name differs according to which version you have

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Add latest gradle version properly in build.gradle file and latest distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file. 
[refer https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html for the latest gradle version of android studio]

Make sure network connectivity is proper [ Network connection should not block upgrading gradle in android studio]. 
After gradle upgrade android studio will prompt alert to accept/decline certificate and we should accept the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it because I'm behind a proxy. I had set the http but not the https proxy in gradle.properties. Https was needed in this case:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<host>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<port>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<host>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<port>
```

Also, take a look at the Android Studio logs for where the error could be.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happen when your have included the dependency and it won't have repository reference like mavenCentral() or jcenter() etc to download it

What I usually do identify such dependency is set gradle to work offline, Android studio will automatically show a dependency which is not locally available, then look for the dependency details in their providers github page like from which repository to pick from and update your repositories and sink it. Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error after upgrading to `Android Studio 3.1.2` with `gradle 4.4` & `plugin 3.1.2`, then tried almost all of the above solutions with generating the same error again & again.

`Invalidate Caches / Restart` finally have done me the favor: `File`>`Invalidate Caches / Restart...`>`Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was caused because cyberoam was blocking my following URL

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I changed(updated) my gradle version and it worked
**Form**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

**To**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check proxy application like fiddler in your system, If its running close that application and restart your android studio

Answer (score 0):

Since this is caused by a misconfiguration of the network you are operating on just setup your smartphone to share its internet connection using USB tethering and use it to download the missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE persistently gives **proxy error** or **Unable to find valid certification path to requested target**, this steps may be solve your problem,

If you have previously made manual Proxy settings, even though we have selected no proxy, you may still be able to see this section in **gradle.properties**.

So you may follow this steps:
1-) Open gradle.properties in your project and delete this items.

[image]

2-) Select No Proxy and Apply
[image]

Try again.May be this solution help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution for key phrases of the messages: “unable to find valid certification path” and “PKIX path building failed“.

These phrases are shown when a SSL certification file can not be found.

Open https://jcenter.bintray.com/ in your browse and export the certificate in cer format.

Put the certificate in Android Studio’s cert folder

```
{your-home-directory}/.AndroidStudio3.0/system/tasks/cacerts
```

Then all went well.

Answer (score -2):

In my case below things identified

Causes -  Take update from remote  OR  Checkout new branch

Resolution - The same issue has been resolved by disconnecting the VPN connection.

After Sync - Connect VPN again do your work as usual.

Comment: not working, vpn is required for internet access.

Comment: In my system, it's working with and without a VPN.
VPN is needed for GIT operations only.
I have also tried all the above solutions but have not resolved the problem.
And then I tried disconnecting VPN and then resolved the problem.