# Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/' Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

My project has no problem till yesterday. Today my team and I get the same problem while building the project.

> Could not GET
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

I have no clue why this error suddenly came to all of us.

What could be the reason? Why **bintray** is not reachable?

**Complete Stack trace**

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preBetaDebugBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfo.getDependencies(LocalTaskInfo.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfo.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskInfo.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:168)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:126)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:190)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:145)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:betaDebugCompileClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1054)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1539)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:211)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:64)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Required by:
    project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$DependencyToComponentIdResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.SelectorState.resolve(SelectorState.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.buildResolveResults(SelectorStateResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.resolveSelectors(SelectorStateResolver.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.selectors.SelectorStateResolver.selectBest(SelectorStateResolver.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelection(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelectionSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:155)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$5.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:533)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:524)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:509)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1514)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.process(DynamicVersionResolver.java:536)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:521)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:290)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:177)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:169)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:111)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenVersionLister.listVersions(MavenVersionLister.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.listModuleVersions(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.doListModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.access$200(ExternalResourceResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:440)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:121)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenMetadataLoader.parseMavenMetadataInfo(MavenMetadataLoader.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.maven.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:50)
    ... 137 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.processResponse(HttpClientHelper.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:304)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 144 more
```

Comment: please refer this link **"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119716/gradle-build-error-unable-to-load-maven-meta-data-from-https-repo1-maven-org"** hope it helps you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem in `Downloads` section with `Partial Outage` in jfrog bintray (https://status.bintray.com/incidents/2wvx6d5f807c):

> Intermittent download issues in Bintray

You can see the current status in https://status.bintray.com/

Comment: Ho.. I'll check it.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem since one hour ago when trying to rebuilding and old project with `google-services plugin` version 3.1.0.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Switch to offline work in Android Studio File->Settings->Build Execution Deployment->Gradle->Check Offline Work

Comment: @MohammedYakubMoriswala: Sady, that doesn't work in my case. Because I just recently wipe out the whole `.gradle` cache in my home directory :'(.

Comment: TY. You save my day