# gradle sync failed after updated android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-intent

I know this was asked a few times already in here, but most answers are for already working projects.

I just downloaded AndroidStudio 3.3.1. Now I started a new project and I instantly get an error, gradle sync failed.

So I watched in my settings, I have checked default gradle, so I changed to local and tried all paths I could find and diffrent help pages told me to try (the default from Android Studio, the one from the new project, one from a project I downloaded) but nothing seemeed to work. Even if it found a gradle, it could not be synced.

I don't have "Offline Work" checked, like it seemes to get problems with that too.

I checked with my work-college, he has the exact same settings, for him they work, for me they don't.

Is there anything else someone know I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you describe the gradle sync error more detailed?

Comment: Course:
As soon as I open the project in AS i get this error:
Configure build failed, Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147334/7649582

Comment: delete your build file. Try with the rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem...

When the project gets built, it builds the gradle online/loads the gradle. As it seems, my company network has blocked this, so it can't get built.

Working over Hotspot it works perfectly fine.

Thanks for all your kind help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project under the Build section, if cleaning the project does not help try invalidate cache and restart project under file section.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but seems like both options don't work, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On the right side of Android Studio there is `source tree` of project. Select `Project` instead of `Android` from source tree options

Now delete the `.idea` and `.gradle` files/folders of project.
After that rebuild your project, if rebuild the project does not working then restart the Android Studio.

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but no didn't worked too

Comment: you have downloaded android studio first time ? or updated only old version

Comment: Installed it the first time