# Python Gtk Server's certificate is not trusted keeps popping up

Tags: python, gtk, ssl-certificate, pycharm

I just set up the pyGTK for my PyCharm through manual install as explained in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066032/2576993). Then "Server's certificate is not trusted" keeps popping every 20-30 minutes.

[Server's certificate is not trusted popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFXpp.png)

I am not even running the program. This would just pop up as I write code. Should I be worried? Can anyone tell me why it appears, and/or how to make it go away?

Comment: I had the same problem. With a bit of googling I landed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192713/android-studio-servers-certificate-is-not-trusted